# Python 26 pkg missing in CentOS 5

Tags: linux, centos, python

Getting following error while accessing :---

```
--> Missing Dependency: python26 is needed by package ambari-server-1.2.3.7-1.noarch (Updates-ambari-1.2.3.7) Error: Missing
Dependency: python26 is needed by package
ambari-server-1.2.3.7-1.noarch (Updates-ambari-1.2.3.7)  You could try
using --skip-broken to work around the problem



root@datanode12.h2.dev.bigdata.sv2.247-inc.net:/etc/yum.repos.d# yumn info python 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror
speeds from cached hostfile  
* base: ftp.uci.edu 
* extras: ftp.uci.edu  
* updates: centos.aol.com 
Installed Packages 
Name              : python 
Arch              : x86_64 
Version           : 2.4.3 
Release           : 56.el5 
Size              : 73 k 
Repo              : installed 
Summary           : An interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language. 
URL               : http://www.python.org/ 
License           : PSF - see LICENSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install/enable the [SCL](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL#head-18f2701f93284a5f1a95b7bb6d430ad4674e315b).

> Enter Software Collections, also known as SCLs. As an example, SCLs
>   allow you to run the default python that comes with CentOS (so yum and
>   other system tools in CentOS work), while also allowing a newer
>   version of python to be installed alongside the default python for use
>   creating and running software with newer requirements.

In this repo you can find more recent releases for development tools. 
. SCL includes the following packages:

- Ruby 1.9.3 (ruby193)
- Python 2.7 (python27)
- Python 3.3 (python33)
- PHP 5.4 (php54)
- Perl 5.16.3 (perl516)
- Node.js 0.10 (nodejs010)
- MariaDB 5.5 (mariadb55)
- MySQL 5.5 (mysql55)
- PostgreSQL 9.2 (postgresql92)

Comment: I am getting following error:--

# yum install centos-release-SCL

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: dist1.800hosting.com
 * extras: centos-mirror.jchost.net
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Setting up Install Process
No package centos-release-SCL available.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The SCL is not available for Centos 5.X But the EPEL has Python 2.6. So you have to enable the CentOS Extras repo and do `sudo yum install epel-release` or without enabling the Extras repo: `wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-5*.rpm` then you can install python26

Comment: Even this is not working.